# how to fix truth value of series error in python

Tags: python

```
if train['Item_Fat_Content']=='LF':
    train['Item_Fat_Content']='Low Fat'
```

error :

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: It seems like `train['Item_Fat_Content']` is probably not a string. What do you get if you print it out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @LakshayGarg why wouldn't you use `.loc`?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, you are correct. I should have used `.loc`. I will delete my original comment. @AVINASHKUMAR If you are feeling lucky, try this: `train.loc[train['Item_Fat_Content'] == 'LF', 'Item_Fat_Content] = 'Low Fat'`. This will probably do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LakshayGarg Thank you sir for your suggestion .It really helped me

Answer (score 0):

You are asking whether the entire column`['Item_Fat_Content']` is `LF`, which isn't a meaningful comparison. Instead, you can use `str.replace`:

```
train['Item_Fat_Content']=train['Item_Fat_Content'].str.replace('LF', 'Low Fat')
```